# Can I use a transistor like a fuse?

Tags: transistors, fuses

I just started learning about transistors, so I was wondering if I could build a circuit where short circuiting across the load caused a transistor to cut off power (like a fuse).

My idea was that when the resistance across the load diminished (short circuit), the current flowing through the reference resistor would diminish thus turning off the transistor controlling the circuit.

[Diagram/Schematic](http://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+2.803162489452614+46+5+50%0Av+288+240+288+160+0+0+40+15+0+0+0.5%0Ar+288+160+208+160+0+5%0At+416+320+288+320+1+1+0.6801673474850795+0.8028897240045327+100%0Ax+230+181+264+184+4+14+Load%0Aw+208+160+208+368+0%0Aw+288+368+208+368+1%0Aw+288+160+288+96+0%0Aw+208+160+208+96+0%0Aw+208+96+224+96+0%0Aw+288+96+272+96+0%0As+224+96+272+96+0+1+false%0Aw+288+160+352+160+1%0Ax+203+70+290+73+4+14+Short%5CsCircuit%0Aw+352+160+416+160+0%0Ar+416+288+416+160+0+250.75%0Al+416+320+416+288+0+1+-0.05661824344037364%0Aw+288+368+288+336+0%0Aw+288+304+288+240+0%0Ao+2+64+6+36874+20+0.1+0+1%0Ao+14+64+0+4097+20+0.4+1+2+14+3%0A38+0+0+1+1000+Voltage%0A38+14+0+1+1000+Resistance%0A)

Forgive me if this question seems to simple, but I searched the forum and can't find anything. I tested this circuit and it does seem to limit the current so I'm wondering why not use this instead of a fuse that gets destroyed by the current?

Comment: The transistor power will destroy it http://tinyurl.com/yxkz57wj

Comment: You can build a short circuit detection circuit that will use transistors to automatically shut off the power, but it is not done as in your schematic. It will be more complicated than a fuse, though, which means it will have more modes of failure. Fuses are usually a last-resort way to stop things from catching on fire if something is going very wrong with your circuit.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I have some IRFZ44N rated for 49A. Is that not enough?

Comment: Looks like the IRFZ44N is an N-channel MOSFET, not a BJT. It will behave very differently, and will also not work as you intend.

Comment: You are using a transistor to shunt current not fuse open as you want. thus a series switch with memory latch or OCP design

Comment: If your device is powered from the mains (plugged into the wall outlet) then it can draw hundreds of amps for a very short time. Mains-powered devices therefore *always* have a fuse.

Comment: https://www.electronicdesign.com/power/current-limiter-offers-circuit-protection-low-voltage-drop

Comment: Please use the built-in circuit editor, I can't see what's on that website.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks for the link. That circuit will take me a long while to understand!

Comment: @Benjamin You can use a transistor (or more commonly, an SCR/thyristor) in what's known as a "crowbar" configuration to protect circuitry. High-current SCRs are used to de-excite generator field windings or shunt away fault current.

Comment: @schadjo, but a crowbar circuit clamps a supply down in order to draw excessive current that will trip a series protective device, most often a fuse. So that doesn't work - they'd need a fuse after all.

Comment: I can say, from experience, that a power transistor can blow quicker than a quick-blow fuse.  But replacing transistors is more expensive and less convenient than replacing fuses.  I ended up using a bigger transistor, so that the fuse blew first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can use a transistor as a fuse. I once built such a circuit for a low power AC/DC supply (I can not show you the full circuit, but you should get the idea):

[image]

Here's how it works: The sense resistor (R16) turns on a transistor (Q6) when the supply return current through R16 is > 0.5A. Then the shutdown signal (SHDN*) is set low and can be used to switch off the load with another transistor (not shown here).

Ok, I admit that this circuit needs at least 2 transistors to replace the fuse. So this circuit shown here is only an overcurrent detector.

The time constants (defined by R15/C19 & R9/C18 in the circuit) will define how long the circuit is switched off before it turns on again.

Comment: This looks more like a [crowbar circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowbar_(circuit)) than a fuse.

Comment: @CalebReister No, a crowbar circuit prevents from overvoltage, while this one cuts off the load when there is too much current (=fuse).

Comment: Isn't that a lot of loss through R15?

Comment: @StefanWyss In order to behave like a fuse it would need to be configured as a switch in series with the load. As it is now, it looks more like some kind of shunt regulator.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, this is not the complete circuit. The part of the circuit shown here only generates the SHDN* signal which can be used to cut off the current with an additional transistor.

Comment: @StefanWyss I see. Maybe you should show more of the circuit.

Comment: @VoltageSpike You mean loss through R16? Yes, there is definitely some loss through R16.

Comment: @CalebReister I'm sorry. I can not show more of the circuit. But I can tell you: There is a switching DC/DC regulator connected to the right that is shutdown with the SHDN* signal in case of an overcurrent situation.

Comment: @StefanWyss How does the SHDN signal shutdown the circuit? Is it using a relay or something else?

Comment: @Benjamin Yes, of course you could also use a relay. But you would need an additional driver for that.